# CSF not blocking traffic to docker

Tags: iptables, docker, csf

CSF is installed at host and following is applied
https://github.com/juli3nk/csf-post-docker

When IP is blocked in CSF, ICMP and request to all other ports gets blocked (except the ones which are configured by docker). If docker0 is listening to some port, it is bypassing the block.
How can I make sure all traffic (including dest:docker0) from a blocked IP get blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.
Sometimes CSF is bypassed and I define rules directly on the Iptables to solve the problem.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -p tcp --destination-port port_number -j DROP
```